# Like a Facebook Wall Post - Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I'm developing a Facebook application that retrieves specific facebook wall posts. I simply want to allow the user to "like" the post from within my application using the javascript sdk.  Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
Issuing a `POST` request to the `likes` connection of the [post object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/#likes) is all you need:

> You can like a Post by issuing a HTTP POST request to the
>   `POST_ID/likes` connection with the `publish_stream` permission. No
>   parameters necessary.

Example:

```
FB.api("/POST_ID/likes", 'post',function(response) {
    if(response === true) {
        alert("done!");
    }
});
```

The above request should return `true` on success.

Comment: Thanks you very much. I really wish Facebook would put some of their billions into better documentation.

Comment: nevermind. I deleted the comment. However, as a follow-up, What would be the best way to determine whether or not a user already likes a particular post. I thought about returning all the likes for a particular post, looping through the values and testing each one against the user's id, but that doesn't seem like an efficient solution.

Comment: @rollsRLS8822: how about asking a new question for that? :-)

Comment: Do you need a special permission for this?

Comment: @Prabhu: Yes, `publish_stream`:`Enables your application to post content, comments, and **likes** to a user's stream and to the streams of the user's friends.`