# Direct Link to 'Like' a Facebook Status - Graph API

Tags: arrays, json, facebook, api

My question is whether there is a way to directly 'like' a specific post/event/link from a website.

Right now I am using the JSON data that is available via https://graph.facebook.com/USERNAME/posts to display the most recent posts for my fan page.

However, I don't know how to 'like' each individual post.  Actually, in the documentation for the graph API posts ( http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ ) there actually is supposed to be a "like" action for each post, but when I check the JSON output, there is no "action" parameter available for my posts.  I've checked them for other very popular fan pages, and seen, on occasion, a "Share" action for some posts, but not a "Like" action.

Is there any sort of direct link that I could use to allow users to like my posts?  (example: http://www.facebook.com/widget/like.php?userId=USER_ID&objectId=FAN_PAGE_ID&postId=POST_ID)

Any help would be welcome here!

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Like a Facebook Wall Post - Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801764/like-a-facebook-wall-post-javascript)

Comment: Yeah, I tried that function, but I couldn't for the life of me get it to return true.  Any suggestions?  Here is my page:  www.dentalawesomeness.com

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!  The Javascript I was using was all correct, but I needed to force users to accept additional permissions for the app in order to be able to "like" the posts.

Thanks!