# How to make 'Like' on Status using access tokens

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, facebook-like, status

i am trying to implement the 'Like' operator by using access tokens from user.
if a user Login in my site using Facebook i will store access token from that user and then using that access token how i can make like on another people's status or photo?

Is it possible using Facebook app ? if yes,can you give me any link to know more about it or just give me brief about it.

Thank you

Comment: Just check this link. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/ is this what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can like a photo by issuing a HTTP POST request to PHOTO_ID/likes connection with the publish_stream permission. No parameters necessary.

If the write is successful, you get a boolean response as return.

Link:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Similarly for liking a status use OBJECT_ID/likes

Comment: but when do STATUS_MESSAGE_ID/likes its done make like on status its just shwoing who all are liked..

Comment: You need to POST ,check this answer this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801764/like-a-facebook-wall-post-javascript